# Sectioned recyclerview Header and sub items in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I've `HashMap` key and `JSONArray` in `Adapter`. How to set header as key and array objects as sub items in RecyclerView?

Follwing is the `HashMap` format for first and second positions getting at adapter class. how to set it in `Adapter`?

```
  0 [{"Imgo":"003f2e1f.jpg"},{"Imgo":"063f2e1f.jpg"}] 
   1 [{"Imgo":"003f2e1f.jpg"}]
```

I'm able to set the header properly. Dont know how to insert the subitems in each header.

Comment: you should use custom adapter for your `RecyclerView`

Comment: In my custom adapter i'm able to set header. How to attach sub items to it?

Comment: You should use a custom adapter that supports two different types.
see [ghostAdapter](https://github.com/sajadshokri/GhostAdapter) lib to support any type of items in recyclerview

Comment: Use adapter layout with TextViewto set the header and linear layout below that and keep adding imageView programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating custom adapter view and passing header array and and subitems array seperately in adapter parameters. I ended up with this logic and it works fine. 
Created seperate header view_holder and subitems viewholder with seperate xml views. The logic will be helpful for others. If any doubts comment here.